# Insert values into tables with a foreign key

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

I want to insert some values in two tables in a loop, but it seems like I can't do it because of the foreign key. However, the same code does work in SQL Server.

This works perfectly in SQL Server:

```
declare @i int = 1

while @i<1200
BEGIN

INSERT INTO DOKUMENTY VALUES(null,null);
INSERT INTO POZYCJE VALUES
( null,@i,RAND()*(10000) ) ,
( null,@i,RAND()*(10000) ),
( null,@i,RAND()*(10000) ),
( null,@i,RAND()*(10000) )

SET @i+=1

END
```

I'm trying to do the same in Firebird:

```
SET TERM #;
execute block 
as
declare variable cnt2 integer = 0;
begin
    while (cnt2 < 1200) do
    begin
        insert into DOKUMENTY(DATA_KSIEGOWANIA) values(current_date);

        insert INTO POZYCJE(ID_DOKUMENTU, KWOTA)
        select (:cnt2), MOD(RAND(),1000) FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL
        select (:cnt2), MOD(RAND(),1000) FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL
        select (:cnt2), MOD(RAND(),1000) FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL
        select (:cnt2), MOD(RAND(),1000) FROM RDB$DATABASE ;
        cnt2 = cnt2 + 1;
    end
end#

SET TERM;#
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
Error: *** IBPP::SQLException ***
Message: isc_dsql_execute2 failed

SQL Message : -530
can't format message 13:470 -- message file C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\firebird.msg not found

Engine Code    : 335544466
Engine Message :
violation of FOREIGN KEY constraint "INTEG_44" on table "POZYCJE"
Foreign key reference target does not exist
Problematic key value is ("ID_DOKUMENTU" = 0)
At block line: 10, col: 9
```

This is how I create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE DOKUMENTY(
ID_DOKUMENTU integer generated by default as identity primary key,
DATA_KSIEGOWANIA DATE
);

CREATE TABLE POZYCJE(
ID_POZYCJI integer generated by default as identity primary key,
ID_DOKUMENTU integer,
FOREIGN KEY(ID_DOKUMENTU) references DOKUMENTY(ID_DOKUMENTU),
KWOTA decimal(18,2)
);
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Firebird code is not equivalent to your SQL Server code. Your SQL Server code starts at `1`, while your Firebird code starts at `0`. The first value generated for an identity column is `1`, not `0`, so your insert fails the foreign key constraint because there is no record in `DOKUMENTY` with `ID_DOKUMENTU = 0`. So, the immediate solution is to use `declare variable cnt2 integer = 1;` instead of `declare variable cnt2 integer = 0;`

However, your code is currently relying on the identity column actually starting at a specific value (`1`), and always incrementing by 1. That is not a safe solution, for example, if you try to run it now with this change, it will fail because the insert of the record with `ID_DOKUMENTU = 1` was undone when your execute block failed, and the next record inserted will have a higher id.

Instead, modify your code to use the actual generated id:

```sql
execute block 
as
declare variable cnt2 integer = 1;
declare variable ID_DOKUMENTU type of column DOKUMENTY.ID_DOKUMENTU;
begin
    while (cnt2 < 1200) do
    begin
        insert into DOKUMENTY(DATA_KSIEGOWANIA) values(current_date) 
           returning ID_DOKUMENTU into ID_DOKUMENTU;

        insert INTO POZYCJE(ID_DOKUMENTU, KWOTA)
        select (:ID_DOKUMENTU), MOD(RAND(),1000) FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL
        select (:ID_DOKUMENTU), MOD(RAND(),1000) FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL
        select (:ID_DOKUMENTU), MOD(RAND(),1000) FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL
        select (:ID_DOKUMENTU), MOD(RAND(),1000) FROM RDB$DATABASE ;
        cnt2 = cnt2 + 1;
    end
end
```

As an aside, `MOD(RAND(),1000)` does not do the same thing as `RAND()*(10000)` in your SQL Server code.